# How can I stop or pause spoken text playback with Siri?

Tags: iphone, siri, voice-dictation, airpods

While listening to a book or article using the Speak Screen function, there is no handsfree way to make it stop. If you take out the AirPods, Siri keeps reading the content out loud from the phone.

Is there anything I can tell Siri to cease the spoken playback so that I am not required to dig my phone out of my pocket in order to listen to the outside world?

I've tried telling Siri things like "stop reading" and even "shut up", but right after Siri stops listening, the spoken text continues and can be distracting/disruptive when listening to the outside world matters.

My best "solution" so far is just pressing the volume button down all the way, but of course I will lose my spot in the book.

Comment: What happens when you squeeze/tap AirPods to play/pause content? In my case it starts playing music from Apple Music - at which point I could take out an AirPod or press pause again.

Comment: Also it sounds like you use that feature often - I recommend checking out Instapaper for listening to articles. It lets you play/pause etc. Obviously there are paid solutions for this too (e.g. Apple News+, audible, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

A *partial* solution is to tell Siri to "mute everything."

This will mute, but not stop the spoken playback, so you'll have to find your place again.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late but I find that using the pause button on AirPods will play a song which pauses the book. if you have wordless song, turn down the volume and activate transparency (especially on AirPods Max) then it will give you a hack pause. some things to note is the the longer the song plays the longer the book takes to restart, if it plays to long it will lose your place.